# Whole house VPN

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I'v been on this quest for a few days now and I haven't found the answers I've been looking for. What I'd like is a "VPN Client" router or server that accepts all LAN traffic and sends it through a "VPN Server".

I have a couple VPS' running as VPN servers. I can obviously connect with my desktop,laptop,tablet,phone no problem -- but I'd like to extend that to the devices that don't have the capabilities like xbox, ps4, media streaming devices.

Is it possible?

Is there a device, such as a router that has this functionality already?

My first thought is setting up a server between the modem and router that would share it's internet connection to the router, which would then extend that to the other devices.

Has anyone tried this before? Thoughts? suggestions?

Thanks for the help.

Edit: Just to clarify, I want to direct *all* of my home internet traffic to a VPN server so all traffic in encrypted (at least to the VPN server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to route ALL traffic from your LAN through VPN, it is easier than routing selected  network traffic.

Be aware, that VPN is not VPN, means not all VPN clients can connect with all VPN servers. For example CiscoVPN is not compatible with OpenVPN.

Depending on your VPN server, you need the VPN client.

If you use OpenVPN server, you could use a device with OpenWRT and OpenVPN client installed as a router in your network.

But you could also use a Windows computer as a network bridge, if the VPN client is Windows based.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. I am testing SoftEther now but I was using OpenVPN a few weeks ago. I'll look into OpenWRT. Both clients will run on a Windows machine so that might be my only option if I cant make something happen with OpenWRT. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider a VPN adapter from [privacyhero.com](http://www.privacyhero.com). Looks like it would convert any router to a VPN router. It uses it's own modern ARM CPU fro VPN encryption letting the router do it's own job. Looks like there is no additional configuration required - plug and play.

The VPN will cover all the devices on your home WiFi network sending all network through VPN or you could decide which devices to connect through VPN and which devices to connect direct.

Answer (score -1):

There are professional VPN-appliances such as Cisco-ASA, they can establish VPN connections and make them available on separate LAN segment.

Comment: You sure the ASA is the right recommendation for a house? Wouldn't that be more for a company, especially with the configuration that isn't exactly trivial in many cases.

Comment: Yeah, I set these up at work for our branch offices, not Cisco brand though. The problem is I'm running VPS' and I wouldn't be able to install networking equipment on the server side.

Answer (score -2):

Your question doesn't appear to make sense.  The whole purpose of a VPN is the encryption it offers when you don't trust the network you are on.  You said you want to take your LAN traffic (I'd HOPE you trust your own LAN) and then encrypt it at the client and send it encrypted to your router where it decrypts and then goes out unencrypted over the internet?  What's the point?  Do you mean you run the VPN client, send it THROUGH your LAN and outbound to a VPN server somewhere else or do you mean that you want to VPN TO your own LAN?  If that's the case, there are routers that act as VPN end-points themselves.  You have the VPN client on the remote computer, it tunnels to your router and from that point you go to wherever you want on your LAN.

The other issue is for your Xbox,PS4, media streamers - the overhead of encrypting then sending to a VPN server and then decrypting would add significant latency.  Forget fast gaming - the lag time you're adding would just kill you and streaming would result in cut outs, pixelations and other artifacts.

Comment: That's not the only reason to use VPN. If you trust your LAN, then you can use it to prevent your ISP from tracking you.

Comment: Exactly, slhck. My ISP throttles Netflix traffic in particular and since we don't subscribe to cable, it sucks waiting for a movie/show to buffer when you have more than adequate internet speeds.